# Ansible: count hosts based on specific fact

Tags: python, ubuntu, ansible, yaml

I'm using Ansible 2.9.13 to manage about 250 ubuntu clients.
If I list all the facts of one client, one of the lines is:

```
"distribution_release": "bionic",
```

What I would like to do now is count the number of machines, which are bionic, focal, and any other version it may find.
So, something like this:

```
bionic:  180
focal:   42
precise: 2
```

Is that possible and if yes, how?

Comment: Please do not edit answers or answers related content in your question. The best would be to [propose this as an edit of dgw's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64803700/edit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `group_by` to create new dynamic groups on the fly.

```
---
 - name: Count hosts based on ansible_distribution_release
   hosts: "{{ target|default('all') }}"
   gather_facts: true

   tasks:
    - name: Create dynamic groups
      group_by:
        key: dist_release_{{ ansible_distribution_release }}

 - name: Make the statistics
   hosts: localhost
   gather_facts: false

   tasks:
     - name: Sample output
       debug:
         msg: "Group {{ item }} has {{ groups[item] | length }} hosts."
       when: item.startswith('dist_release_')
       loop: "{{ groups|flatten(levels=1) }}"
```

The first play creates dynamic groups based on `{{ ansible_distribution_release }}` and all groups start with the prefix `dist_`.

In the second play the dynamic groups will just be used to create a rather ugly but working statistics of the groups and the number of hosts within the groups.

If you like you could just use Jinja2 template to create a nice output to a file.

Answer (score 1):

Create the dictionary from the *hostvars* in a single task

```yaml
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        distros: "{{ distros|default({})|
                     combine({ item.0: item.1|length }) }}"
      loop: "{{ hostvars|dict2items|
                groupby('value.ansible_distribution_release') }}"
      run_once: true
```

---

The same dictionary can be created without iteration when *json_query* is used

```yaml
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        distros: "{{ dict(keys|zip(vals)) }}"
      vars:
        dist: "{{ hostvars|dict2items|
                  json_query('[].{distro: value.ansible_distribution_release}')|
                  groupby('distro') }}"
        keys: "{{ dist|map('first')|list }}"
        vals: "{{ dist|map('last')|map('length')|list }}"
      run_once: true
```

---

Next option is to create the dictionary with the help of a custom filter

```py
shell> cat filter_plugins/count.py
def count(l):
    d = {}
    for i in set(l):
        d[i] = l.count(i)
    return d

class FilterModule(object):

        def filters(self):
            return {
                'count': count,
                }
```

```yaml
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        distros: "{{ hostvars|
                     json_query('*.ansible_distribution_release')|
                     count}}"
      run_once: true
```